# ASP .NET MVC 4 AuthorizeAttribute and ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to implement Active Directory role based authorization in my ASP.NET MVC 4 Intranet Web Application by using the AuthorizeAttribute.

```
[Authorize(Roles = "CONTOSO\\G_Helpdesk")]
public ActionResult Index() {
   return View();
}
```

This should only allow members of the group CONTOSO\G_Helpdesk be able to view the index page. My development Virtual Machine and Web Server are both **NOT domain members**. So I thought I should configure a ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider. My web.config is shown below.

```
<authentication mode="Windows"/>
<authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>

<membership defaultProvider="ADMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="ADMembershipProvider"
      type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider,
      System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
      PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
      connectionStringName="ADService"
      connectionUsername="CONTOSO\User"
      connectionPassword="myPassword"
      attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName"/>
  </providers>
</membership>

<connectionStrings>
  <add name="ADService" connectionString="LDAP://dc1/DC=CONTOSO,DC=com" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Now here's the problem. I'm not able to login using an active directory user who is member of the CONTOSO\G_Helpdesk group. In fact I'm not able to login at all. When I change the attribute to the lines below, I am able to login using a local account.

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Index() {
   return View();
}
```

Does the AuthorizeAttribute even use the membership provider? I think it totally ignores it.

Comment: I don't think you need the `CONTOSO` part in the `connectionUsername`, trying using just the username instead.

Comment: Unfortunately that isn't working. My guess is the Membership provider isn't used at all. Is there any way to log/debug this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out I'm not thinking in the right direction. I won't be able to authenticate from a standalone webserver using AD credentials while using Windows Authentication. [Source](http://forums.iis.net/p/1191919/2030853.aspx).

I have two options.

- Make the webserver member of the Domain.
- Use Forms authentication.

I hope this answer will save people who are struggling with the same problem some time.